# What causes Automatic Suspend to fire up on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, suspend, gdm, screensaver

I have Ubuntu 18.04 where X11 is implemented by Xorg using gdm3 as a login shell.

I load to dconf following .ini file (in addition to Ubuntu 18.04 gdm3 defaults):

```
# New added
[org/gnome/control-center]
last-panel='power'

[org/gnome/desktop/screensaver]
idle-activation-enabled=false
lock-delay=uint32 0
lock-enabled=false

# Settings --> Power --> Screen Blank --> Never
[org/gnome/desktop/session]
idle-delay=uint32 0

# Settings --> Power --> Automatic Suspend --> When idle --> Off (0 minutes)
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
idle-dim=false
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=900
sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing'
```

From the content is seen that I disable screensaver from blanking and loosing its brightness, and that, indeed, works! However the message `Automatic suspend` is still present after 900 seconds as stated in `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=900`. P.S changing to `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0` doesn't solve my problem!

I also tried to disable screensaver from the Xorg perspective:

```
xset s noblank
```

However nothing works for me, the screen is still suspended after 900 seconds, i.e 15 mins. What is interesting is that I have Ubuntu 20.04 for comparison, and when I use the same settings for Ubuntu 20.04 - `no Automatic Suspend` is fired!

How could I solve that `Automatic Suspend` issue on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: If you do not want to find the cause why not disable the suspend and hibernate systemd unit? That should kill it :P

Comment: @Rinzwind it may sound weird by I have tried that and no success :D, I have created `nosuspend.conf` file in a `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf.d/nosuspend.conf` directory as proposed in a https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend